# How to use multiple IPs for different browser tabs/programs in an AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, dns, ip, cloud

So when I purchase a AWS ec2 large instance I want to do the following:

1. Use a linux AMI
2. Install for example Gnome so I can view it like a GUI
3. Install a browser
4. Open multiple different browsers/tabs
5. When I go to a whatismyip.com I want it to show a different IP address in each tab/browser

So is there a function or possibility to right click a program and say like "connect to the internet using ... IP address"?

I want to use the built in IP addresses provided by Amazon, elastic IP adresses.

Comment: It may be possible using iptables owner matches, but far from "right click" solution...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use different proxies from different browser instances. Proxy setup should then be in a way that different IP adresses are used.

Comment: I also want to use it for non-browser programs which interact with the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to forgo a browser the tor project has an api which will let you leverage its routing capabilities programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use proxy for each browser, for each tab is not allowed.

Once you have 3 valid transparent proxies (preferable SOCKS 4/5) you will have 3 unique IP addresses.